# How do I solve this differential equation? $y'=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So, hey.
The equation is $y'=\frac{y}{x+y^3}$
So, I get something like this: $y'\left(x+y^3 \right)-y=0$, which I can't actually solve. I must admit I am slightly confused how to attack this one.
What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one possible method: consider $x$ as a function of $y$. Then the equation becomes
$$
\frac{dx}{dy}=\frac{x+y^3}{y}=\frac{x}{y}+y^2.
$$
This is a linear equation.

Anther possibility (which I have not checked) is to look for an integrating factor.

Answer (score 0):

$y'=\frac{y}{x+y^3}\Leftrightarrow(x+y^3)dy=ydx$.

Case 1: $y=0$.

Case 2: $y\neq0$, then $$\frac{1}{y^2}[(x+y^3)dy-ydx]=ydy-xd\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{y}dx=d(\frac{1}{2}y^2-\frac{x}{y})$$
$\frac{x}{y}-\frac{1}{2}y^2=C$.

The solution to the ODE is $x=\frac{1}{2}y^3+Cy$.